# How do I process a single result from an sql query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the stored $_SESSION username (stored in the $username variable) to obtain the user's id using the following query in PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
```

I then process the query result as follows:

```
$userid = mysql_fetch_row($query);
```

Because I am logged in as a demo user, the user id that this query should return is: 12. However, when I echo $userid['id'] I get this output:

```
1111
```

Is this not a proper way of processing the data from the query? Should I be using mysql_fetch_row() if I am only expecting a single result?

I have also tried running the query in PHPMyAdmin and it returns the expected result just fine.

Comment: try running the query in PHPMyadmin or some other database manager you've installed and have access to it, and see if both results matches.

Comment: Conflict... You are searching for field "username" then echoing "id".

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Is the username unique in your sql table?
Is there other user with same name ? Your process method should works.

Comment: [I hope to dog you're escaping `$username` properly](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Bojangles: What is the proper method of escaping $username?

Answer (score 1):

fetch the results using:

```
    $query="SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'";
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
                $id=$row[0]; //change to the column number you are using to store id
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   while($userid = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      echo $userid['id'].'<br />';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is vulnerable to **SQL injection attacks** and you are using *deprecated* libraries which will be removed from future versions of PHP.

I recommend moving to mysqli ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)), which will help to protect you from injection attacks with its prepared statements ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).

Your query appears correct. If you run `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'demo'` in PHPMyAdmin or SQL command line, what do you get? Is `username` a `UNIQUE` field or do you have two accounts called `demo`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have changed the code and am now using mysqli, but I am still getting the same result. To answer your last question, username IS a unique field and when I run the query in PHPMyAdmin I get the expected result of 12, but not when I run it in php...

Comment: Is PHP connecting to the same `mysql` instance as you are? Try using `SELECT * FROM users;`, `->fetch_assoc` and echoing all values in a `foreach` loop.